# Finding unique Google Mid from GEG in big-query

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm new to big-query so I apologize in advance if my question is unclear or simple :)

As part of an assignment I am looking to see unique mentions of Morocco within Israeli newspapers in order to show growing interest in the Morocco-Israel relationships as talks increased between the two countries.
I'm trying to find the articles within gdelt, specifically gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.geg_gcnlapi . While I have the code to run from an earlier assignment on a different entity, I do not know how to find the unique entity.mid for Morocco (in the assignment we used '/m/0fm2h' for Benjamin Netanyahu).

I seem to have trouble finding the unique mid. I tried within the geg_gcnlapi database, which was implied to be the right location in this article (https://blog.gdeltproject.org/announcing-the-global-entity-graph-geg-and-a-new-11-billion-entity-dataset/) but perhaps I didn't do something right, or it's the wrong place.

For refrence, here is the code I am trying to run:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `dotted-vim-311413.Class56146_Week_6.geg_morocco_in_leading_il_en_domains` AS
SELECT
  date,
  url,
  lang,
  score,
  entity.name AS name,
  entity.type AS type,
  entity.mid AS mid,
  entity.wikipediaUrl AS wikipediaUrl,
  entity.numMentions AS numMentions,
  entity.avgSalience AS avgSalience
FROM
  `dotted-vim-311413.Class56146_Week_6.geg_il_domain`,
  UNNEST(entities) AS entity
WHERE
  entity.mid = '***Morocco***'
  AND NET.REG_DOMAIN(url) IN ('globes.co.il',
    'israeltoday.co.il');
```

The third-to-last line is the mid entry for which I'm looking for the unique ID for Morocco.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT entity.name,
  entity.mid,
  entity.avgSalience,
  entity.wikipediaURL
FROM
  `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.geg_gcnlapi`,
  UNNEST(entities) AS entity
WHERE
  LOWER(entity.name) LIKE '%morocco%'
  AND DATE(date) >= "2021-06-20"
ORDER BY
  avgSalience DESC;
  -- Top results show that Morocco's MID is /m/04wgh
```